# Button disabled but looks active

Tags: asp.net, html, css, cross-browser

So I have a button that is currently set to disabled, and in IE it is greyed out, but in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, it is disabled but still looks active.

Button code

```
<tr valign="middle">
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
        <asp:Button ID="DownloadButton" runat="server" Text="Download" Width="85px" CssClass="ESTableHeaderL" OnClick="DownloadButton_Click" />
    </td>      
  </tr>
```

And my code behind

```
protected void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (ddBusinessMonth.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        DownloadButton.Enabled = false;
        ShowClientMessageBox("No Data found for downloading");
    }
....

}
```

Is there anything I can do to make it look the same as in IE?

Thanks

Comment: that allows it to be disabled but in the browsers it doesnt grey it out

Comment: Every browser has it's own default styling. You may however enforce your own style. For this you must create custom CSS classes and apply them at your will

Comment: what is a css for `ESTableHeaderL`? It may cause the issue, as each browser has some default styles for disabled buttons. Possibly you have redefined it somehow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [**:disabled selector**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-disabled) can be used with CSS3

```
input[type="button"]:disabled
{
background:#dddddd;
}
```

Browser Compatibility:

```
 IE8+ FF1.5+ SA3.1+ OP9.2+ CH2+
```

**For ASP.NET:**

Add a CssClass attribute to your server-side button and refer it to the class containing the above CSS.

Comment: Might want to add `input[type="submit"]:disabled` as well.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but how do I apply a style to an object in asp.net

Comment: Add a CssClass attribute to your server-side button and refer it to the class containing the above CSS.

Comment: Great solution, but the choice of sample style is unfortunate, as (at least for me, on Google Chrome 49) it doesn't actually change the button appearance. I suggest  using `color: #ccc;` which grays out the button's _text_.

Answer (score 1):

you could programatically assign a css class if its disabled

```
if (ddBusinessMonth.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        DownloadButton.Enabled = false;
        DownloadButton.CssClass = "disabledbutton";
        ShowClientMessageBox("No Data found for downloading");
    }
```

css

```
.disabledbutton{
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

Comment: Can I do at cliend side. I have lot of butttons inside table actually button are working as disabled but visually they are enabled ie 9 its disabled for disable and ie11 its enabled . I know the id for the button . Is there anyway out to do from css only don't want to use codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Framerwork 4 renders controls differently. Add the below to your we.config, and the disabled button will greyed as usual.

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"/>
```

Comment: My web.config already has this configuration, but the disabled button still can't show obviously.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way without using a custom CSS class (nothing against style sheets) that can be completed in the code behind.  The following will set the background color of your download button to green (I think it's green, I'm colorblind :-| ):

```
DownloadButton.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#28C523");
```